# Setting a Publishing Hyperlink Field Value that has no Value

Tags: 2007, development, client-object-model, publishing

I am using the Object Model and the Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.LinkFieldValue namespace in an attempt to set the value of a Hyperlink Column on a SharePoint 2007 Publishing Site.

However, if the **field has no value** prior to my update, I get  System.ArgumentNullException when I attempt the assignment.

```
using Pub = Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;

int id = 1;
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.List.GetItemById(itemId);
if(item.Fields.ContainsField("MyHyperlink"))
{
    Pub.Fields.LinkFieldValue destination = 
        new Pub.Fields.LinkFieldValue("<a href=\"www.google.com\">Link</a>");
    item["MyHyperlink"] = destination; //Null Exception here for item["MyHyperlink"]
    item.SystemUpdate(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to post a link, but did you check out this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.fields.linkfieldvalue(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks. - My error was more along the lines that I was using a different column type than I had thought. Your link worked once I created a site column using the type "Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing" the code above worked. I was getting the null error because the site column was actually the "Hyperlink or Picture" column it just expected a string with the URL and Display Text comma delimited